# Information Rights Management (IRM) Support

Tags: windows-phone-7

are there any solutions to open IRM-protected files on windows phone 7? Help me please to find this out. If any source code is available it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released an update to support Information Rights Management (IRM) Protected EMail on Windows Phone (mango), if customer have Windows 7, they will have to apply free updated to get up 7.5 (Mango). so they can use such capability.

- http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2011/07/26/windows-phone-mango-released-to-manufacturing.aspx
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/windows_phone_for_it_pros/archive/2011/11/08/windows-phone-7-5-and-irm.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The integrated Outlook client on WP7 supports IRM mail.  As of 7.5, the integrated Office clients do not support IRM, however, so you won't be able to read the word document in the DNF message.